# Axios doesn't delete data from database - empyt array Vuejs and Laravel

Tags: database, laravel, vue.js

I Have an issue with my code. My axios delete request doesn't delete data from database. I get response 200 but it's all.

Component

```
    deleteComment(index){
      axios.delete(this.uri + this.comments[index].id)
      .catch(error=>{
        console.log(error)
      });
    }
```

Controller

```
  public function destroy(BlogComments $cid){

    $comments->delete();

    return response()->json([
      'comments'=> $id,
      'Message'=> "OK!"
    ]);

  }
```

Console -> Network

```
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/blog-comments/4
Request Method: DELETE
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

When I make response form controller, I have only empty arrays

```
comments[]
```

**UPDATE**

I fixed it.

I replaced

```
Route::resources('/blog-comments', 'DashboardBlogCommentsController');
```

By

```
Route::delete('/blog-comments/{id}', 'DashboardBlogCommentsController@destroy');
```

Why resources doesn't work ? I used the same method in my other page and it's worked

```
Route::resource('/advantages', 'DashboardAdvantagesController');
```

```
  public function destroy(HomepageAdvantages $advantage){


  $advantage->delete();
  return response()->json([
    'advantage'=>$advantage,
    'message'=> 'task created'
  ]);


  }
```

Comment: Before the edit, you did not have the variable $comments defined  on your destroy function. So why this: `$comments->delete(); `?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a answer for:

> Why resources doesn't work ?

**Route**

This is maybe a typo in your edit and not in your code, but is not `resources`:

```
Route::resources('/blog-comments', 'DashboardBlogCommentsController');
```

is `resource`:

```
Route::resource('/blog-comments', 'DashboardBlogCommentsController');
```

And based on the code before the UPDATE of your question:

**Controller** `DashboardBlogCommentsController`

```
public function destroy(BlogComments $comment){ 
    // use delete() on the variable where you assigned the object
    $comment->delete();

    return response()->json([ 
        // 'comments'=> $id, this no needed, the comment doesn't exist anymore
        'message' => 'OK!' ], 202);
}
```

Hope it's helps